# Calling `scipy.optimize.minimize` inside an `sklearn` classifier makes it break in a parallel job

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, scipy, thread-safety, scipy-optimize

I have ran into a silent crash that I am attributing to breaking thread-safety.

Here is the details of what happened. First I have defined a custom `sklearn` estimator, that uses `scipy.optimize` at fitting time, similar to:

```py
class CustomClassifier(BaseEstimator, ClassifierMixin):

    ...

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        ...
        #optimizes with respect to some metric by using scipy.optimize.minimize
        ...
        return self

    ...
```

Downstream, I run a cross-validated measurement of its performance, looking like:

```py
cv_errors = cross_val_score( CustomClassifier(), X, y, n_jobs=-1)
```

`cross_val_score` is the `sklearn` out-of-the-box function, `n_jobs=-1` means that I am asking for it to be parallelised on as many cores as available.

The output is that my `cv_errors` is an array of `NaN`s. After doing some bug chasing, I notice that setting `n_jobs=1` gives me an array populated by the errors, as expected. It looks like the parallelisation step, coupled with the use of `scipy.optimize.minimize` is the culprit.

Is there are way to have it working in parallel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a way around here:

```py
with parallel_backend('multiprocessing'):
    cv_errors = cross_val_score( CustomClassifier(), X, y, n_jobs=-1, error_score='raise')
```

seems to be safe here. If anyone has explanation of what is happening behind the scenes, and why the 'locky' backend breaks while 'multiprocessing' does not, I am listening. Also, setting `error_score='raise'` means that a crash will not be silenced.